# Should we allow edits that change the in-answer order of multiple approaches?

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits

I"ve just come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3144774) edit where the answer contains two approaches to the solution, one of them being an update 3 years later. The edit switches the two approaches to make the most recent answer stand out more.

I can see where he's coming from, but I'm not entirely sure if this should be considered as "too minor". Is this is an edit we should allow or not?

Comment: I'd consider it unnecessary, but no harm being done there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Too minor" because the answer is only 5 lines. Had it been many lines, it *may* have been a different story. I don't think there should be an absolute rule here - it should be decided on a case-by-case basis, depending on how much value the reordering adds.

I see some possible improvements to make the edit more substantial:

1. The `"UPDATE"` part should probably showed an example as well
2. I find the timestamp somewhat pointless
3. `"add the"` -> `"add that the"`
4. Get rid of the `"this is an update"` look - just say `"The correct way to do this is..."` and then `"An alternate way is..."`.

(I also made those edits)

Answer (score 3):

I think the edit was rejected for the correct reason – too minor.

That being said, I would have no problem if people wanted to move around the contents of an answer to make it more legible. Just in this case, little or no benefit was obtained. Had the answer being significantly longer (such that scrolling was required to see the update), it might have been a worthy edit.